# How to load all images on assets folder once?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

**Error message**

> The method 'add' was called on null. I/flutter (10160): Receiver: null
>   I/flutter (10160): Tried calling: add(Instance of 'SvgPicture')
>   I/flutter (10160):

I need to add all SVG images to grid view. I used **flutter_svg** plugin. I added to pubspec.yaml.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<SvgPicture> _getImages(){
    var image;
    for(int i = 1; i < 425; i++){
      var x = SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/images/Defect/icon-$i.svg',
      );
      image.add(x);
    }
    return image;
  }
```

**added all images in upper method**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
```

**added futurebuilder for load all images**

```
        child: FutureBuilder<SvgPicture>(
            future: _getImages(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            List values = snapshot.data;
            int count = 1;
```

**added listview to load all images**

```
            return ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 0.0, left: 0.0),
              itemCount: count,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return GridView.count(
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  //  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                  children: List.generate(values.length, (index) {
                    return GridTile(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                      //  onTap: () => sub(values[index].childId),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Card(
                              //color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 1.5)),
```

**added svgPicture widget for view all images**

```
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SvgPicture.asset(
                                      '${values[index]}',
                                      height: 50.0,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

**added Text widget for view all images file name**

```
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                values[index],
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following changes:

- change the return type to a List of SvgPicture.
- initialize the `images` variable.
- add the `async` keyword to your method.

  ```
  Future<List<SvgPicture>> _getImages() async{
    List<SvgPicture> images = List(); 
    for(int i = 1; i < 425; i++){
      var x = SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/images/Defect/icon-$i.svg',
      );
      images.add(x);
    }
    return images;
  }
  ```